# Form won't display correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am having a rather strange issue with Visual Studio 2010. For some reason, whenever I debug or build my program, my "MainForm" appears as it does in the second image, yet is supposed to appear like the form in the designer in the first image (for some reason, the correct form displays in the designer, but not when compiled)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I have checked the `.Visible` options on all of the controls, as well as the startup options presented in the properties dialog and `program.cs` and they are all correct. Here's `program.cs`:

```
namespace SouthWest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //-----DO NOT EDIT-----
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            //---------------------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if you are missing this in the MainForm constructor InitializeComponent();

Comment: @harrison - Disable each tab in the form. And introduce one tab and one control at time. If that gives you the control with the error then post some more info.

Comment: @Sharkz, the problem isn't with the tabs I don't think because the form itself isn't even displaying it's MainForm.Text() property...

Comment: @Sharkz, I checked an it's there :/

Comment: Also ^^ was meant for @PreetSangha :)

Comment: @Harrison try to debug inside the initialize component and see if all the objects are being created correctly or not.

Comment: The "step-into" seems to pass over the majority of things in the designer file...which would logically seem the cause of the problem...now the question becomes how to fix it...

Comment: Are u using mdi form layout...

Comment: Nope...and I'm not sure that that would effect it... :/

Comment: @HarrisonTotty You say stepping through skips over 'the vast majority' of the designer code. Can you identify where the InitializeComponent method exits, and why?

Comment: Well it exists within the MainForm.Designer.cs file as it should...I assume it is executed shortly after Application.Run(new MainForm()). I have not touched this code because it is application-generated. I will post any bit of my SC as you guys see fit...I've tried many fixes to include changing Application.Run(new MainForm()) to MainForm x = new MainForm(); and then x.show();

Comment: @Harrison: Can you attach the whole code for the form, in cs and designer both.

Comment: @RJLohan, I actually realized what you were talking about...It seems as though I accidentally deleted the InitializeComponent() method in the MainForm.cs file...However, even after replacing this to it's original public MainForm() { InitializeComponent(); }, I am still getting a blank form :(

Comment: @HarrisonTotty are you saying that when you are stepping through your InitializeComponents Method you are skipping lines of Code? If so have you tried to Clean/Rebuild your Project ?

Comment: @MarkHall, I truely feel like an idiot for not trying this...Yes, that worked lol. I know i'm radiating serious amounts of noob right now but I guess I had to do something stupid eventually.

Comment: @HarrisonTotty The reason that I knew it, is because I **have** seen it before. :)

Comment: @MarkHall, At least I won't run into this problem ever again...Thanks for that crucial piece of information and thanks to everyone! This website rules!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Re-add this to MainForm.cs:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then, go to `Build > Clean and then Build > Rebuild`

Everytime in the constructor of the form make sure `InitializeComponent()` method is there.

This method initializes your components i.e. controls in your form (hence the name `InitializeComponent`) so that memory are allotted to them (and event handlers are added to them if you have added them).

Comment: I am using vb.net, where do i add this method? I tried inside load method of the form but did not work